# Compare 2 columns from separate sheets and return value from adjacent cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to compare two columns and find a match then return value from adjacent cell. I searched for answers on google but I could not find an answer that I could use. Most everything I saw did not use script but a sheets formula. the few I functions I did see didn't fit either.

```
function findDuplicate() {
  
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Working'); 
  var s1 = sheet1.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Match'); 
  var s2 = sheet1.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  var mv = s1 === s2;
  var matchedValue = mv.getvalue();
  return matchedValue.offset(0, 1);

}
```

I am unsure how to fully do this. I understand my code is incomplete but I started down the path the best I know how. And for ease of time, yes I need this to be done in Apps Script as it will be part of another bunch of code.

example sheet link below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKFoS17le-Y5SAOecoLE4EJxiKqKVjRLRHtMzwHNwxM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### Find match and return next column

```
function findDuplicate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Working'); 
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange('H1:H' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Match'); 
  const vs2 = sh1.getRange('A1:B' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  let o = [];
  vs1.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == vs2[i][0]) {
      o.push(vs2[i][1]);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  return o;
}
```

Comment: Use case. I need to search column 8 of my "Working" sheet and column 1 of my "Match" sheet if a match is found return the email adjacent to the match. I don't see how this is done in the above code. my example sheet has this outlined.

Comment: What sheet and what column do you wish to return

Comment: I changed the column in the working sheet.  I never follow links to personal spreadsheets. I recommend you always post everything needed in your question

Comment: "Working" column 8  to "Match" column 1. output column 2 of "Match" column 8  and 1 are names column 2 is email. I'm trying to find the email of match

Comment: That's what I have now.